# Wordpress finding posts on 404 page

Tags: loop, database, 404-error

I'm struggling with a strange issue on my WP : when I'm on a 404 page, the wp loop is finding posts, but it's not supposed find posts on the 404 page.

How I know WP find posts ? Because I wrote something like that on my 404.php file :

```
@while(have_posts()) @php the_post() @endphp
  {!! get_the_title() !!}
@endwhile
@if (!have_posts())
  404 content here
@endif
```

And it display titles...

What I did :

- disable all plugins. Not changing anything
- reset my roots/sage theme to the origin, not working
- changing theme : not working
- start my wp with a clean DB : IT WORKS !

But I have no idea how to fix it... Do you have an idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: start wp with clean db and add few posts in it and see if it still outputs posts?

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing the full code of your 404 page.

Comment: In my post, I explained that starting with a new DB is working. So it came from the DB, but I don't know from where...